# Heap memory problems while running android gradle script in Jenkins on a hosteurope server

Tags: java, android, jenkins, heap-memory, android-gradle-plugin

For an android project using the gradle build system I want to run tests and the build within jenkins on a virtual server provided by hosteurope.

The system uses

- Debian Wheezy (7.5)
- OpenJDK-7 (7u55-2.4.7-1~deb7u1)
- Jenkins(1.564) as standalone server.

For running the jenkins job I installed

- Gradle plugin(1.23)
- Android Emulator Plugin(2.11.1)

For the build process itself Android Build Tools (19.1) are used.

The build fails everytime during the preDexDebug task presenting following error message:

```
:app:preDexDebugError: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/dx --dex --output    /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_project/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/ormlite-core-4.48-bdb20e19ede8fedfab10bb99de3affa6b8ed6e4d.jar /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.j256.ormlite/ormlite-core/4.48/e579bd2905d0399af5029aaaf9817d5fa0ca88a5/ormlite-core-4.48.jar
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
    Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

With applied "--debug" switch insufficient heap memory is presented as the cause for the failure.

Unfortunatly, setting JAVA_ARGS parameter in /etc/default/jenkins or DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS in gradlew script to "-Xms128m -Xmx512" does not solve the problem. 
The only working solution I found is using _JAVA_OPTIONS.

Therefor I added _JAVA_OPTIONS as an environment variable within jenkins configuration.

Go to "Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->Configure System" in the menu and activate checkbox "Environment variables" within section "Global properties".
Afterwards hit the "Add" button and insert _JAVA_OPTIONS in textfield labeled "name" and '-Xms64M -Xmx512M' in textfield labeled "value".

Accordingly to a german FAQ entry on the hosteurope website (http://faq.hosteurope.de/index.php?cpid=13918) the problem is caused by a wrong calculation of available memory within the hosteurope VPS.

Comment: I am not sure about what you are asking.  Did setting those environment variables solve the problem?  Have you tried to open a ticket with the system owner about this?  By the way, in my experience, -Xmx512 seems a bit low for a full gradle build and tests (it depends on your project, of course).  Have you tried with -Xmx2048 or something like that?

Comment: The problem is solved by using the values presented in the question. I tried higher values like -Xmx2048 in the gradlew script without success. At the moment the project is very small but it is likely that I have to use higher values in _JAVA_OPTIONS in the future.

I wanted to mark the question as answered or answer it myself but because of a lack of reputation points I have to wait some hours before I can do this. Since it took me several hours to figure out the problem I wanted to share the solution to others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for the explained problem is using _JAVA_OPTIONS as environment variable within jenkins as it is presented in the question. It will affect all Java processes started by jenkins which might lead to other problems. Hopefully the next Java or Hosteurope VPS update solves the issue completly.